# Can a input box achieve this type of lookup?

Tags: excel, vba

Say I have column A (a job code: 10001) and columns CE/CF have the business units in the company where that job would qualify for non-traditional hours.

Job Code|Job Title|Business Segment 1|Business Segment 2

10001|Customer Support Spec|Operations|Treasury Management

10001|Customer Support Spec|Operations|Mail Services

10001|Custmer Support Spec|Operations|Currencies

If I had one job, but its sectioned out to 3 different BU lvl 2 segments, how could I make something in VBA where it would prompt an input box and just as for the job code in the first column, and a text display would show the Business Units that it fell under?

Something like:

```
Sub JobCodeSearch()


JobCode = Application.InputBox("Please provide a job code", "job code", Type:=1)

Set found = Range("A:A").Find(what:=JobCode, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

If found Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Your job code was not found"
Else
    'I would want a dialogue box showing all of the values in the 3rd and 4th columns from where it matches that job code
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: There're quite a few ways, though I like using the Find()/FindNext() function, storing values as a string, and outputting the string (val = val & ", ")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a Range.Find loop.  It would look something like this:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim lJobCode As Long
    Dim sFirst As String
    Dim sResults As String

    lJobCode = Int(Application.InputBox("Please provide a job code", "Job Code", Type:=1))
    If lJobCode = 0 Then Exit Sub   'Pressed cancel

    With ActiveSheet.Columns("A")
        Set rFound = .Find(lJobCode, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            sFirst = rFound.Address
            Do
                sResults = sResults & Chr(10) & rFound.Offset(, 2).Value & " | " & rFound.Offset(, 3).Value
                Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
            Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirst
            MsgBox "Business units for Job Code [" & lJobCode & "]:" & sResults
        Else
            MsgBox "Job Code [" & lJobCode & "] not found.", , "Error"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: So this works, but I had to switch the columns to columns G & H to fit my non dummy data.

this line only spits out the data in column H 

     `sResults = sResults & Chr(10) & rFound.Offset(, 7).Value & "  " & rFound.Offset(, 8).Value`

any idea why not both columns?

Comment: Also, what would I do if I wanted to reference column B text strings? I know I'd change to `With ActiveSheet.Columns("B")` and I would change the `lJobCode` datatype to `Type:=2` to reference text string. It doesn't seem to want to work though

Comment: @nicklanta You'd need to change the variable you're assigning the InputBox value to.  So you'd have to change that to be a `String` instead of `Long`.  You'll also need to remove the `Int()` conversion.  Lastly, you'll need to adjust the `.Offset` references so that they are pulling data from the correct columns.

Comment: If you want the sub to exit properly when the user presses cancel, you'd also need to change that line to `If <YourVarName> = "False" Then Exit Sub`

Comment: Now I have two different working applications, solution verified! Thanks a bunch

Comment: I do have one more question. What if instead of a msgbox--displaying the output, I'd have it print the values into a new sheet in column A? Is that a difficult thing to change in the code?

Comment: You'd have to change how you collect results so that instead of adding to a string it outputs to cells (or collects the results in an array and then outputs the array to cells)